# Form nested JSON form object in angular component HTML

Tags: angular, typescript

I am very new to angular and trying to add a form. I am using ngForm in component class:

Component class method:

```
public addEndpoint(endpointForm: NgForm){
  this.endpointService.addEndpoint(endpointForm.value).subscribe(res => {  });
}
```

Component HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Endpoint Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Endpoint Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="wavefrontInstance">Wavefront Host/IP</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="https://0.0.0.0" name="wavefrontInstance" [(ngModel)]="wavefrontInstance" required>
</div>
<div class="for-group">
    <label for="waveFrontProxyPort">Wavefront Proxy Port</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="2878" name="waveFrontProxyPort" [(ngModel)]="waveFrontProxyPort" required>
</div>
```

POST body output:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "wavefrontInstance": "string",
  "waveFrontProxyPort": "string"
}
```

**My POST request is failing as the post body formation is incorrect.**

I want to get the form POST body output like:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "connection": {
    "wavefrontInstance": "string",
    "waveFrontProxyPort": "string"
  }
}
```

For that I modified my current component html component as:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Endpoint Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Endpoint Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="connection.wavefrontInstance">Wavefront Host/IP</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="https://0.0.0.0" name="connection.wavefrontInstance" [(ngModel)]="connection.wavefrontInstance" required>
</div>
<div class="for-group">
    <label for="connection.waveFrontProxyPort">Wavefront Proxy Port</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="2878" name="connection.waveFrontProxyPort" [(ngModel)]="connection.waveFrontProxyPort" required>
</div>
```

Error I am getting is: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'wavefrontInstance' of undefined`

I looked at many example but I found them with implementation of model class, I don't want to implement any model class for connection props. Even I do not want to modify the component class method. I want some solution in HTML only in order to get the correct JSON object. Do we have a way to get this?

Comment: You should take a look to ReactiveForms (also named Model driven forms). With this kind of forms, it's your object (and its structre) that will drive the form; So when you'll post  it you will have the data in the "shape" you need.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue using `fieldset` , Modified the HTML as below and it worked!

```
<fieldset ngModelGroup="connection">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Endpoint Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Endpoint Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="wavefrontInstance">Wavefront Host/IP</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="https://0.0.0.0" name="wavefrontInstance" [(ngModel)]="wavefrontInstance" required>
</div>
<div class="for-group">
    <label for="waveFrontProxyPort">Wavefront Proxy Port</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="2878" name="waveFrontProxyPort" [(ngModel)]="waveFrontProxyPort" required>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ngModelGroup` and remove "connection." from input name tag.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Endpoint Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Endpoint Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" required>
</div>

<div ngModelGroup="connection">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="wavefrontInstance">Wavefront Host/IP</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="https://0.0.0.0" name="wavefrontInstance" [(ngModel)]="wavefrontInstance" required>
</div>
<div class="for-group">
    <label for="connection.waveFrontProxyPort">Wavefront Proxy Port</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="2878" name="waveFrontProxyPort" [(ngModel)]="waveFrontProxyPort" required>
</div>
</div>
```

PS: This has been asked a while back.. hope it helps someone stuck.